# Full Text Search "Contains" is slower than "Like %"

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains, sql-like

I have an issue with Full-Text Indexing on SQL Server 2008 x64.

I have three tables:

TableA with 90 000 rows

TableB with 12 000 000 rows

TableC with 22 000 000 rows

I created FTS catalogs with autopopulation.

When I queried TableA :

```
Select * from TableA where Contains(field1, '"j*"')
```

I see 11000 records less then 1 second

But when I queried TableB or TableC with same query I see 250 records in 2 seconds. It is obviously very slow.

Query with "like %" instead of "contains" executes less then 1 second for the same tables.

Can the problem exist because of large tables B and C? TableA queried successfully.

Maybe those tables need more time for indexing? (but they are indexing(populating) 3 days already)

Some details:

For tables B and C I always see "Population Status = Processing notifications" (9)

Property "TableFulltextDocsProcessed" always increases

(My SQL Server have a mirrored instance.)

Comment: *"but they are indexing(populating) 3 days already"* <-- you are saying the index is not finished building yet? Then of course it is slower with no index. You also said the status is always "processing notifications". Is the SQL Server starving MSFTESQL/MSSEARCH of memory, maybe that is why it takes ages to complete the full text index?

Comment: "but they are indexing(populating) 3 days already" <-- Indixing should be finished: "Item Count" property of FTS Catalog is equals to row count of necessary table and I wait 3 days and querying is still slow. 

What is strange that TableA with not to much records is queried successfully. So I think that Tables B and C need more time to build some cache or something...

About memory settings: they are default. And I don't see any memory issues on the server.

Also my server have a mirrored instance. Can this influence to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if your contains query really use the fulltext index. I think it has to do a full table scan. As I have understood the full-text index index words and word stem in different languages.  Your like query

```
Select * from TableA where Contains(field1, '"j*"')
```

only has the char '**j**'  in it if you did the same search with

```
Select field1 from TableA where Contains(field1, 'fish')
```

compared to

```
Select field1 from TableA where field1 like '%fish%'
```

In this quote they talk a lot about words not characters.
[SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Search: Internals and Enhancements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345119%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

> Full-text search allows fast and
>   flexible indexing for keyword-based
>   query of text data stored in a SQL
>   Server database. Unlike the LIKE
>   predicate, which only works on
>   character patterns, full-text queries
>   perform a linguistic search against
>   this data, operating on words and
>   phrases based on rules of a particular
>   language.

So I am wondering if the j* works if the phrase:  'j' has to be a word in the languages that the fulltext is used with..
see
[CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

> Specifies a match of words or phrases
>   beginning with the specified text.
>   Enclose a prefix term in double
>   quotation marks ("") and add an
>   asterisk (*) before the ending
>   quotation mark, so that all text
>   starting with the simple term
>   specified before the asterisk is
>   matched. The clause should be
>   specified this way: CONTAINS (column,
>   '"text*"'). The asterisk matches zero,
>   one, or more characters (of the root
>   word or words in the word or phrase)

What do the execution plans look like?